# How to count the number of same value across multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

```
A B C
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 3 3
3 2 1
```

I want to add a column `D` which represent the same numbers of values across `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
D
2
2
3
1
```

Comment: Do you mean... the _maximum_ number of repeated values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use `stack` + `groupby` + `value_counts`:

```
df['D'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().max(level=0)
```

```
df

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  2  1  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  3  2  1  1
```

If you want the number which has the highest mode, chain a `groupby` + `head` call -

```
v = (df.stack()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .value_counts()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .head(1)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)

1    2
2    2
3    3
1    1
dtype: int64
```

```
df['Num'], df['Num_Mode'] = v.index, v.values   # to assign it
```

If multiple numbers has the same highest mode, only one of them are returned.

---

**Option 2**
Another option inspired by @Wen, using `apply` with `pd.Series.mode` -

```
df['D'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x).max())
```

Or,

```
df['D'] = df.apply(pd.Series.mode, 1).max(1).astype(int)
```

```
df

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  2  1  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  3  2  1  1
```

Comment: THANKS！I have another question, if I can know which one is the mode?

Comment: @danche `df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(1)`... See edit.

Comment: @danche You want the number which has the mode, and not the mode value itself? I'm not sure what your expected output is.

Answer (score 4):

scipy mode can return the count as well

```
from scipy import stats
df['D']=stats.mode(df.values,1)[1]
df
Out[829]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  2  1  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  3  2  1  1
```

More Info:

```
stats.mode(df.values,1)
Out[830]: 
ModeResult(mode=array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [1]], dtype=int64), count=array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [2]]))
```